# Mage::getDesign()->getTheme('frontend') has an equivalent in magento 2

Tags: magento2, theme

```
Mage::getDesign()->getTheme('frontend')
```

Just wondering if there is an equivalent of theme name in Magento 2?

Comment: You want to get current theme name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\Magento\Framework\View\DesignInterface`:

```
/** @var \Magento\Framework\View\DesignInterface $design **/

$design->getDesignTheme();
```

See more `app/etc/di.xml`

```
<preference for="Magento\Framework\View\DesignInterface" type="Magento\Theme\Model\View\Design\Proxy" />
```

Comment: Great tip mate. Was able to get the code by using your suggestion:

$design->getDesignTheme()->getCode();